# Filter for post_thumbnail: link to small src and add data-attribute

Tags: images, post-thumbnails, filters, thumbnails

I wonder how I can link manually to the smallest filesize for `the_post_thumbnail()` within its filter function …

```
add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'post_thumbnail_html', 10, 3 );

function post_thumbnail_html( $html, $post_id, $post_image_id ) {

    $html = '<a href="' . get_permalink( $post_id ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( get_post_field( 'post_title', $post_id ) ) . '">' . '<img class="digest" src="' . $post_image_id . '" alt="' . esc_attr( get_post_field( 'post_title', $post_id ) ) . '" />' . '</a>';

    return $html;

}
```

So now my image src is just the post_id (e.g. 38). How can I link to the smallest filesize possible and add another data-attribute that links to the largest file?

My output should finally look like this …

```
<img class="digest" src="small-post-thumbnail.jpg" data-fullsrc="full-post-thumbnail.jpg" alt="something" />
```

Thank you in advance!

edit/update: I'd love to do the same for images inside `the_content()`. Any idea how to apply the same thing to normal images in posts. The src should always hold the smallest size wordpress creates and the data attribute should link to the largest filesize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you already know your $post_image_id, you can use [wp_get_attachment_src()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src)

```
$small = wp_get_attachment_src($post_image_id, 'smallest-size');
$large = wp_get_attachment_src($post_image_id, 'full');

$smallURL = $small[0];
$largeURL = $large[0];
```

where 'smallest-size' is the name of the image-size you have predefined in [add_image_size()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size)

Comment: Thank you, this works fine! Any ideas on how I could apply the same thing to normal images inside `the_content()`?

Comment: Like @janw said, i think that'll be tough. I've seen people do it with some regex to filter the images markup from `the_content` filter and re-processing them to fit.

Comment: Check this answer just posted -> http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/53597/7890

Answer (score 0):

`post_thumbnail_html` has 5 arguments not 3 like you use, in arg #5 are the attributes.
The thumbs should already be the smallest file.

http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/post_thumbnail_html?version=3.3&file=wp-includes/post-thumbnail-template.php

Applying this to `the_content` will be much harder