# Filter to modify post_title after image upload?

Tags: images, uploads, filters, title

When I upload images, Wordpress 3.4.2 sets the Title to the base of the filename, such as "DSCN1234" or "IMG_1234". I'd like the Title to be left blank.

The code that sets the Title during the upload seems to be in "wp-admin/includes/media.php" in the function `media_handle_upload()`, here:

```
// Construct the attachment array
$attachment = array_merge( array(
   'post_mime_type' => $type,
   'guid' => $url,
   'post_parent' => $post_id,
   'post_title' => $title,
   'post_content' => $content,
), $post_data );
```

If I just change it to `'post_title' => "",` it fixes it, but I understand that the core code shouldn't be modified.

Is there a filter I can use to modify the Title after it's been set by the upload handler? I tried `wp_handle_upload` and `wp_handle_upload_prefilter` but they don't give me access to the `post_title` data.

The filter `attachment_fields_to_edit` does give me access to `post_title`, but it's fired for every image when editing a gallery -- I just want to modify the `post_title` of a single image immediately after it's uploaded. (if the user manually sets the Title to the filename afterward, I don't want to remove it.) Any other ideas?

---

UPDATE: well, I just discovered that the `post_title` is set back to the file name every time the gallery is updated (re-sorting images, etc.) And even if I use the `attachment_fields_to_edit` filter to clear the `post_title`, it doesn't stay cleared because when I click Save Changes, something is apparently not liking the fact that I've set the Title field to be empty even though it's a required field (red asterisk next to it). Other ideas appreciated.

Thanks!
Russell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Answering my own question, with help from @brasofilo)

Wordpress 3.5 has a great new Media manager, and it no longer requires the Title to be filled in for images. It also no longer fills in the Title automatically when reorganizing images in a Gallery. It does, however, still fill in the Title with the image filename when uploading the image, such as "DSCN1234". But this can be prevented by adding the following code to the `functions.php` file in your theme:

```
add_action( 'add_attachment', 'wpse_70093_modify_uploaded_file_title' );

function wpse_70093_modify_uploaded_file_title( $attachment_ID ) 
{
    $the_post = array();
    $the_post['ID'] = $attachment_ID;
    $the_post['post_title'] = '';
    wp_update_post( $the_post );
}
```

After the image is uploaded, the Title will be empty, and it'll stay that way unless you specifically set it to something - even if the image is edited in Wordpress.

Comment: I would really like to have a plugin or setting for this in one of the upcoming versions of Wordpress.
I just don't want to have it in my template-files because it's nothing specially for _my_ template.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin you could use for this purpose http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/img-title-removal/ this plugin would hide the title at all (not sure if this is what you want to accomplish?)

Comment: Thanks - I saw that actually, but I don't really want to remove the title attribute completely, I just don't want it to be set to the image filename. If the user chooses to set the title to something, I don't want to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

What could be done is set the title of all uploads to "Untitled".

Then, filter `the_title` and return an empty string if the attachent title matches the default.

The basic idea is:

```
add_action( 'add_attachment', 'wpse_70093_modify_uploaded_file_title' );
add_filter( 'the_title', 'wpse_70093_display_untitled', 10, 2 );

function wpse_70093_modify_uploaded_file_title( $attachment_ID ) 
{
    $the_post = array();
    $the_post['ID'] = $attachment_ID;
    $the_post['post_title'] = 'Untitled';
    wp_update_post( $the_post );
}

function wpse_70093_display_untitled( $title, $id )
{
    if( 'attachment' != get_post_type( $id ) )
        return $title;

    if( is_admin() )
        return $title;

    if( !is_admin() && 'Untitled' == $title ) 
        return '';

    return $title;
}
```

**[update]**
I was missing the frontend approach. Filtering `the_title` only works for the `attachment.php` page.

The images inserted through the editor have to be [filtered](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/53577/12615) with:

```
add_filter('image_send_to_editor', 'wpse_53577_img_wrapper', 20, 8);

function wpse_53577_img_wrapper($html, $id, $caption, $title, $align, $url, $size, $alt) 
{
    /* Manipulate $html result */
    return $html;
}
```

The `[gallery]` shortcode has to be rebuild with [`post_gallery`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=%2badd_filter%20%2bpost_gallery).

Other cases have to be dealt with individually.

Comment: I think you're really close with this answer. The "add_attachment" function works great, and sets the newly-uploaded image file to have a post_title of "Untitled". However, the second function only gets called for posts, and not for media files. I added a call to error_log() to display the output of get_post_type($id) when the blog is displayed, and it always displays "post", so the media file is never processed. Any other ideas? Thanks!

Comment: @RussellG, I've modified the `display_untitled` logic, and did a fast test drive, seems workable, give it a shot.

Comment: Thanks, but when I display the blog page with the images on it, the `display_untitled` function doesn't seem to be called at all for the images, just for the post itself. If I print the return from `get_post_type($id)` at the top of the function, it always prints "post". Shouldn't it be called for each image somewhere, or am I missing something?

Comment: @RussellG, answer updated.

Comment: Thanks, but when I add the filter for `image_send_to_editor`, the function doesn't seem to be called at all. I can't find official documentation for `image_send_to_editor` but it sounds like it's related to editing images. What action on the blog triggers it? What I think I'm looking for is something that modifies the image's "post_title" attribute when it's displayed to the user on a blog page - right?

Comment: I guess I didn't exemplified well enough. I'll review this later. In the meantime, *research* in this Stack how the filter works. Then, of course, you need to explicit where and how are your images being handled in the frontend.

Comment: After updating my site to Wordpress 3.5, I realized this was much simpler now, since it no longer requires a Title on images, and doesn't fill in the Title when reordering images. If you'll modify your answer to mention this, and just include the `add_attachment` action (but change 'Untitled' to an empty string ''), I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: @RussellG, I don't see the edit... maybe it was declined in the review process... and maybe it's the case that you write your own Answer explaining how it goes in 3.5.